# Tensors and the gradient - how to see that the gradient if formed by covariant elements and basis.

Tags: tensors

In Introduction to Tensor Analysis and the Calculus of Moving Surfaces
by Pavel Grinfeld the gradient is addressed as a problem to be solved because both the coefficients and the basis vectors are covariant, leading to an object that it is not invariant with changes in coordinates:

> Equation (6.48) $\left(\nabla F =\sum_i \frac{\partial F}{\partial Z^i}\bf Z_i \right)$ has several elements, of which all but one are proper from the tensor points of view. The collection of partial derivatives $∂ F∕∂ Z^ i$ is a tensor. The covariant tensor $\bf Z_i$ is a tensor. Their product  is a tensor of order two. However, the contraction is invalid because both tensors are covariant.

What does he mean by "The collection of partial derivatives $∂ F∕∂ Z^ i$ is a tensor."? Is $F$ a scalar function? I guess $Z^i$ are coordinates. I guess the proof is to see what happens under a change in coordinates to the expression in terms of the Jacobian, but I don't know how to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

$F$ is a scalar field

From [here](https://www.math.drexel.edu/%7Edws57/Tensor_Calc_and_Moving_Surfaces_Exercises_New.pdf):

> Let $Z, Z'$ be two coordinate systems. Write the unprimed coordinates in terms of the primed coordinates: $Z(Z').$ Then

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial F(Z)}{\partial Z^{i'}} &= 
\frac{\partial F(Z(Z'))}{\partial Z^{i'}}\\
&= \frac{\partial F}{\partial Z^{i}}\frac{\partial Z^i}{\partial Z^{i'}}\\
&=  \frac{\partial F}{\partial Z^{i}} J^i_{i'}
\end{align}$$

> so $\frac{\partial F}{\partial Z^{i}}$ is a covariant tensor.